# Overloading doesn't work for <<

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I have this code and I can't figure overloading the << operator:

```
 ostream& operator<<(ostream& out)
     {int check=0;  
    node *temp;     
    temp=this->head->next;
    if(this->head->info==0)
        out<<"- ";  
    while(temp!=NULL)
        {   if(temp->info)
            {out<<temp->info<<" ";
            check=1;
        temp=temp->next;}
            else    if(temp->info==0&&check==1)
            {out<<temp->info<<" ";
                temp=temp->next;}
            else temp=temp->next;
        }
        return out;

    }
```

I have a struct in the class and wish to output a large number. The large number is created with a linked list. The overloading method is inside the class and i get the error: no match for operator << when I use

```
 cout<< B;
```

inside main.

More details on the code above. the check variable is to make sure that a number like 00100 is printed 100. if head->info ==0 number is negative , if it's 1, number is positive. I start at head->next cause the first node has the number sign.

Comment: `operator<<` overloads can't be member functions if you want the standard syntax - you would have to call it as `B << cout`, which is not what you expect.

Comment: Apparently 'B << cout' is working correctly... it just doesn't look right. I read about what you said here, that operator<< overloads should be non-member. But I can't figure how to take all that code outside my class and keep the variables. When I tried doing that I got variable not declared errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator<<` overloads can't be member functions if you want the standard syntax - you would have to call it as `B << cout`, which is far from nice.
(As for all binary operators, `B.operator<<(cout)` means that `B` is the left-hand side.)

Here's what I usually do.

A named regular member function:

```
ostream& output(ostream& out) const
{
    // Your code here.
}
```

and an operator that just calls that:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyClass& c) 
{ 
    return c.output(os); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it in a wrong way... overloading operator inside the class lets you use the class as a left operand of the operator... so basically you would be able doing `B << cout;` now.

You need to overload operator as a function **in a namespace where your class is defined** like this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, TYPE_OF_YOUR_CLASS_HERE v)
{
    int check=0;  
    node *temp;     
    temp=b.head->next;
    if(v.head->info==0)
        out<<"- ";  
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {   
        if(v.info) {
            out<<v.info<<" ";
            check=1;
            temp=temp->next;
        } else if(temp->info==0&&check==1) {
            out<<temp->info<<" ";
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        else 
            temp=temp->next;
    }
    return out;
}
```

As Alper suggested you also need to make the operator<< the friend of your class to be able to access the private fields of the class:

```
class MY_CLASS {
    ...
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, MY_CLASS v);
};
```

Comment: Ok, so, I took the function out of the class and I made it friend. Only problem is that I have undeclared variables(node/temp was not declared in this scope, and class MY_CLASS, has no member named info. I assume this is because I have not put the function in a namespace of which you were talking earlier. Problem is... I have no idea what that is or what to look after.

Comment: First of all your overloading operator needs to be in the same namespace as your type. You also need to place in your source code includes of all header files you are using and namespace usings: `using namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE;` for all namespace that are used in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer a global `operator<<` overload if you want to allow expressions where the class type happens to be on the right hand side of a binary operator.

`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const YourClassType& B)`

In addition, make it `friend` if it needs to access private members. Otherwise simply make it non-friend non-member function.